# Why the same POST request works in POSTMAN but not in browser AJAX (404 Not Found)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have created ASP.NET WebAPI with the following POST method:

```
[HttpPost, Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] StudentDto student)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var maxId = conrollerStudents.Max(x => x.ID);
    student.ID = ++maxId;
    conrollerStudents.Add(student);

    InsertStudentIntoDatabase(student);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetStudent", new { id = student.ID }, student);
}
```

WebAPI's config:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableCors();

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();  
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

This API method works only in POSTMAN where I got 201 as result of the POST request. When I move this request into JavaScript-Jquery-AJAX with the following code (auto-generated by POSTMAN). I get the following error message:

```
{
    "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:59523/api/students'.",
    "MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'Students' that matches the request."
}
```

This is the auto-generated JavaScript-Jquery-AJAX Code, which happens to do not work:

```
// ...
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:59523/api/students",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\n  \"FirstName\": \"Sample\",\n  \"LastName\": \"Sample\",\n  \"City\": \"Sample\",\n  \"ListOfCourses\": []\n}"
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
// ...
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: From where do you call this AJAX ?

Comment: It is triggerd by the button click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem relates to the incorrect WebAPI configuration file: *Web.config*. I have changed the *system.webServer* section to:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH" modules="IsapiModule" 
          scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />      
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
          preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the method to be the default action on that controller, try setting the default action to Index and renaming your method as Index.

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: It did not help. Sill 404.

Comment: Can you share the full raw content of the request from Postman?

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the Postman. If this is what you asked for. https://imgur.com/a/j307u

Comment: you've got a header set in postman that I can't see, check that the content types match